# Convert properties to json with jq

Tags: json, properties, internationalization, jq, converters

I have some properties like that.
There may be some spaces between key and equal.

```
error.code.400                  = Incorrect Request.
error.code.404                  = Requested resource not available.
error.code.500                  = Internal server error. It will soon be processed.
error.msg.1                     = Sorry for the inconvenience.<br />The page you have requested was not normally processed.
error.msg.2                     = Access Denied. Please contact the administrator.
```

I wish to convert them to json with jq like that

```
message: {
    error: {
        code: {
            400: 'Incorrect Request.',
            404: 'Requested resource not available.',
            500: 'Internal server error. It will soon be processed.'
        },
        msg: {
            1: 'Sorry for the inconvenience.<br />The page you have requested was not normally processed.',
            2: 'Access Denied. Please contact the administrator.'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  That's a nice problem statement, but normally questions should pinpoint the specific difficulty encountered, e.g. in the context of a specific attempt to solve the problem.  As they say, SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Using an invocation with the -nR (or -n -R) options, the following generates valid JSON, which you can readily massage (or mangle) into the format you want:

```
def trim: sub("^ +";"")|sub(" +$"; ""); 

reduce inputs as $in (null;
  ($in | capture("(?<k>^[^=]*)=(?<v>.*)" ) | map_values(trim)) as $kv
  | setpath( $kv.k | split("."); $kv.v) )
```